# Partition table - by non clustered index

Tags: partitioning, azure-sql-database

I aim to partition an existing table on datetime column
using range partition by month.
My sql environment is Azure sql paas.

My work flow is:

1. Create partition function - until 2025 by month interval
2. Create partition schema
3. Create non clustered index on Created column asending
4. Create a truncate partition stored procedure

My questions are:

1. Can i create a partition on non clustered index?
2. Is there a downtime when creating partition (schema lock) that i need to consider?

Here is the code for every process:

1. Create partition function

```
        DECLARE @DatePartitionFunction nvarchar(max) = 
        N'CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION DatePartitionFunctionByMonth2025 (datetime2) 
        AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('  
    DECLARE @i datetime2 = '20221001'  
    WHILE @i < '20250201'  
    BEGIN  
    SET @DatePartitionFunction += '''' + CAST(@i as nvarchar(10)) + '''' + N', ';  
    SET @i = DATEADD(MM, 1, @i);  
    END  
    SET @DatePartitionFunction += '''' + CAST(@i as nvarchar(10))+ '''' + N');';  
    --select @DatePartitionFunction
    EXEC sp_executesql @DatePartitionFunction;  
    GO
```

2. Partition schema

```
  CREATE PARTITION SCHEME DatesToFilegroup  
    AS PARTITION DatePartitionFunctionByMonth2025  
    ALL TO ( [PRIMARY] );
```

3. Create non clustered index on Created column asending

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS IX_SagaEvents_Created ON [Saga].[SagaEvents]
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SagaEvents_Created] ON [Saga].[SagaEvents]
(
    [Created] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF)
ON DatesToFilegroup([Created])
GO
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with partitioning?

Comment: it's an audit table that i would like to keep data only up until 2 month. I plan on using truncate partition for partitions older than two month

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense.